# Background is not shown in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code that I cannot see my background image?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Protfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <style>
           section {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What about me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav
        <section id="home" style="background: url(images/bg.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;"></section>
    </body>
</html>
```

My index.html and the image folder is in the same level. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am new in web developing. I don't know jsfiddle.

Comment: Post your code on `https://jsfiddle.net/`. This will allow everyone to see a live demo and edit/debug the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it... I forgot the ">" in the closing "nav" tag!